# blur-admin でスタイルが適用されない

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sass

https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/
これをビルドしてみたのですがスタイルが適用されません

---

実行したのはこれだけです

```
git clone https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin.git
cd blur-admin
npm install

rm ~/.eslintrc.json # これをしないと gulp "angular" is not defined というエラーが出る

gulp serve
```

ブラウザの画面を起動すると、個別のグラフ等のスタイルは適用されていますが
全体的なレイアウトスタイルが適用されていません
SASS周りの何かがおかしいんだと思うんですが
anglar も gulp も初めてで何からしらべればいいかがわからず困っています

以下の起動時のログですが SASSの色周りで DEPRECATION WARNING がでるだけでとくにエラー等は出ていません

```
[15:45:12] Using gulpfile ~/git/blur-admin/gulpfile.js
[15:45:12] Starting 'scripts'...
[15:45:12] Starting 'styles'...
[15:45:13] Starting 'stylesAuth'...
[15:45:13] Starting 'styles404'...
[15:45:13] Starting 'copyVendorImages'...

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 41 of ...
The operation `#209e91 minus 24` is deprecated and will be an error in future versions.
Consider using Sass's color functions instead.
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#other_color_functions

[15:45:14] Finished 'styles404' after 1.45 s
[15:45:14] Starting 'inject404'...
[15:45:14] Finished 'stylesAuth' after 1.47 s
[15:45:14] Starting 'injectAuth'...
[15:45:15] gulp-inject 1 files into 404.html.
[15:45:15] gulp-inject 1 files into auth.html.
[15:45:15] Finished 'inject404' after 202 ms
[15:45:15] gulp-inject 1 files into reg.html.
[15:45:15] Finished 'injectAuth' after 244 ms
[15:45:15] gulp-inject 1 files into main.scss.
[15:45:15] Finished 'styles' after 2.48 s
[15:45:16] Finished 'copyVendorImages' after 2.55 s
[15:45:16] all files 244.11 kB
[15:45:16] Finished 'scripts' after 3.64 s
[15:45:16] Starting 'inject'...
[15:45:16] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[15:45:16] gulp-inject 139 files into index.html.
[15:45:16] Finished 'inject' after 134 ms
[15:45:16] Starting 'watch'...
[15:45:16] Finished 'watch' after 123 ms
[15:45:16] Starting 'serve'...
[15:45:16] Finished 'serve' after 30 ms
[BS] [BrowserSync SPA] Running...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3002/
    External: http://192.168.1.5:3002/
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3003
 UI External: http://192.168.1.5:3003
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: .tmp/serve
[Browsersync] Serving files from: src
```

---

環境は MacOS

```
node -v
v11.15.0

gulp --version
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1

npm -v
7.19.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずAngularJS 1.x系なのでNodeのバージョンを下げた方が良いです
8か10あたりのバージョンになると思います（Nodeは偶数バージョンが安定版です）
両バージョン試しましたが私の環境では `gulp "angular" is not defined` は発生しませんでした

`gulp serve` 後、コンソールログに以下のエラーが出力されていました

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.zoomControl.update is not a function
```

エラー内容から以下のissueを見つけました
https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/issues/511

コメント通り `gulp-inject` パッケージをアップグレードするとcssが反映されました

**package.json**

```
// 4.x.xから5系に書き換え
"gulp-inject": "~5.0.5",
```

修正後に再度 `npm install && gulp serve` を実行すればcss適用されると思います